# Coverting datetime.datetime into timestamp in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in pandas which contains `datetime.datetime` array. For instance the rows has the following format:

```
datetime.datetime(2017,12,31,0,0)
```

I want to convert this to TimeStamp such that I get:

```
Timestamp('2017-12-31 00:00:00')
```

as output, I wonder how one does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html

So maybe: `df['datetime'].to_timestamp`